# Batch file running Java program on User Login/ Logoff

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, group-policy

I have a Java application packaged up as a jar that I want to run when the user logs in and logs out on Windows.

I have added the command to do this in a batch file and added it to the group policy login/ logoff with some logging so I can debug it.

When I run the batch file logged in as an admin user it executes correctly, however when I log out/ in, it skips over the java command in the batch file.

I'm guessing this is probably due to permissions issues with the local system running a java application, is there anyway I can get around this/ an alternative?

Comment: Is the correct java exe on the `PATH`? What does the exe log? All the relevant paths in the batch file resolves correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a scheduled task [triggered](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx) to launch at startup. You can use a specific user, and you probably will receive a better log if the process fails.

Comment: My Java app requires the use of a security manger which is specified in the java command along with the java.policy file. Triggering it to launch when I log it gives a security exception - I'm guessing it's because the java.policy file isn't being correctly loaded. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Scrap the comment above, was a path issue. OK so it runs successfully using the triggered launch under task schedule. Can you trigger a task on all user logins / logoffs?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've managed to figure out what was going wrong - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was 'skipping' over the Java Execution because there was a path formatting issue and I forgot to add the standard error output to the logging ('2>&1' at the end of the stream) I didn't notice the error.

Specifically in my java.policy file the path used '\' instead of '/'.